# Print every 3 strings who are start from special symbols

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I have file like this:

```
user bbbb 
user bbbb 
user bbbb 
Server sent 214221
Server receive 134212
user aaaa 
Server sent 2222
Server receive 1231231
user cccc 
Server sent 32424
Server receive 3242352
user dddd 
Server sent 522
Server receivce 21652532
user eeee 
user ffff 
Server sent 32563
Server receive 9045432
user aaaa 
Server sent 3256
Server receive 923211
user gggg 
Server sent 75425
Server receive 125463
user dddd 
user dddd 
Server sent 35262
Server receive 456438
```

I want to parse this file for extract every 3 string(first string started "user", second - "Server sent", third - "Server receive".

I want to have result similar to this:

```
user bbbb 
Server sent 214221
Server receive 134212
user aaaa 
Server sent 2222
Server receive 1231231
user cccc 
Server sent 32424
Server receive 3242352
user dddd 
Server sent 522
Server receivce 21652532
user ffff 
Server sent 32563
Server receive 9045432
user aaaa 
Server sent 3256
Server receive 923211
user gggg 
Server sent 75425
Server receive 125463
user dddd 
Server sent 35262
Server receive 456438
```

I want skip all repetition of string "user".
Just need this strings:

```
user
Server sent
Server receive
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
grep -A 1 -B 1 'Server sent' file.txt | sed '/^--$/d'
```

(OR)

```
grep -C 1 'Server sent' file.txt | sed '/^--$/d'
```